# http stream to iphone using uiwebview is blocked by proxy or something similar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, uiwebview, stream

Here is my problem
I use the mediaplayer integrated in a uiwebview to show a video which is streamed from a url i load into the uiwebview.
The video consists of a ad-preroll and the video itself.
In some wireless networks however the preroll is shown, but the video itself is blocked somehow.
Is there any possiblity for me to check weather the proxy of the wireless network blocks the video? And why is the preroll video working and the other video not?
If i can check if the video is blocked, is there a possibilty for me to make the phone switch to 3g instead of using wifi?

Thx for the answers.
Mav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have an answer for your question directly, but if you are thinking about streaming video over 3G then make sure you check these out.

[Requirements For Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5)

[HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)